# Запись определенного формата сигнала

Tags: c#

Есть определенный формат сигнала .adc, нужно представить заголовок этого файла в реализации c#, вот пример части этого формата в бинарном представлении:

флаги................. long  (DWORD) - 4 байта
младший бит:
целочисленные отсчеты      - 00000000H
отсчеты с плавающей точкой - 00000001H
первый бит:
отсчеты комплексные        - 00000002H
отсчеты некомплексные      - 00000000H
резерв заголовка......           - 8 байт
желательно заполнить нулями
отсчеты   - (массив переменной длины)
Некомплексные отсчеты:
целочисленные      - shortint* - 2N байт
с плавающей точкой - float*     - 4N байт
Комплексные отсчеты:
Записаны подряд пары вида (реальная,мнимая) части
целочисленные      - shortint* - 4N байт
если разрядность АЦП выше 16, то целочисленные отсчеты
представлены следующим образом:
  - int*       - 8N байт
с плавающей точкой - float*     - 8N байт
Кто-нибудь может помочь реализовать(привести пример), либо же подсказать где можно прочитать по этому поводу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте структуру и энумератор флагов

```csharp
// структуру и энумератор расположите снаружи класса, просто в неймспейсе
public enum HeaderFlag : long
{
    Flag1 = 1,
    Flag2 = 2,
    Flag3 = 4,
    Flag4 = 8
}

public struct Header
{
    [Flags]
    public HeaderFlag Flags { get; set; }
    public uint CountersInt { get; set; }
    public float CountersFloat { get; set; }
    // и так далее
}
```

Затем при считайте заголовок в массив байт `byte[]` и разберите поток байт в цикле присваивая значения полей

```csharp
byte[] headerArray = ...;

Header header = new Header();
byte[] temp;

temp = headerArray.Take(4).ToArray();
header.Flags = ...;

temp = headerArray.Skip(4).Take(4).ToArray();
header.CountersInt = ...;
}
```

Как преобразовывать массив байт в числа, можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-int).

Наверно еще можно попробовать использовать [маршалинг](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798986/marshal-a-c-struct-containing-a-variable-length-array).